# Android - Access Object Through Out Application

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I have the below class which I have tried implementing as a Parcelable class.
The problem is the class requires a context, so I can't make it Parcelable.
I need to be able to access an object of the class across different activities in order to share bitmaps used by the application. Some of the same bitmaps are used across the application.

I have an issue with running out of memory, so I am trying to use this as a solution.

```
public class ImageManager implements Parcelable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 66;
    private HashMap<Integer, Bitmap> mBitmaps;
    private HashMap<Integer, Drawable> mDrawables;
    private Context mContext;


    private boolean mActive = true;

    public ImageManager(Context c) {
        mBitmaps = new HashMap<Integer, Bitmap>();
        mDrawables = new HashMap<Integer, Drawable>();
        mContext = c;
    }

    public ImageManager(Parcel in) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // We need to share and cache resources between objects to save on memory.
    public Bitmap getBitmap(int resource) {
        if (mActive) {
            if (!mBitmaps.containsKey(resource)) {
                mBitmaps.put(resource,
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), resource));
            }
            return mBitmaps.get(resource);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Drawable getDrawable(int resource) {
        if (mActive) {
            if (!mDrawables.containsKey(resource)) {
                mDrawables.put(resource, mContext.getResources().getDrawable(resource));
            }
            return mDrawables.get(resource);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void recycleBitmaps() {
        Iterator itr = mBitmaps.entrySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
            ((Bitmap) e.getValue()).recycle();
        }
        mBitmaps.clear();
    }

    public ImageManager setActive(boolean b) {
        mActive = b;
        return this;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return mActive;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        dest.writeValue(mBitmaps);
        dest.writeValue(mDrawables);
        //dest.writeValue(mContext);
        dest.writeByte((byte) (mActive ? 0x01 : 0x00));

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ImageManager> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ImageManager>() {
        public ImageManager createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ImageManager(in);
        }

        public ImageManager[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ImageManager[size];
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: So what is the issue with above code

Comment: I need to be able to access the same object through out the application, through out different activities. Currently I am creating a new object for each activity to be able to use the class.

Comment: Create static object and use it throughout the app..

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton object...for the class and use it across whole app...this will ensure your object requirement and also one object across whole app

Sample code:

```
public static <<Class name>> getInstance(Context m1Context){

            if (minstance==null){

            minstance=new Database(m1Context);
            }
            return minstance;


        }
```